# google search show "missing amp"

Tags: amp-html

AMP page: https://www.acuvuearabia.com/freetrial-amp
canonical page: https://www.acuvuearabia.com/freetrial

The AMP page validation is correct on validation page: https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=91w2VdfmpqD6XRdsMZYR7w
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cBIb.jpg) but in Google search result it show "Missing amp" icon:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AYfK.jpg) Any suggestion with AMP page's setting?

Comment: try this  ⚡ in place of amp copy from here : https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fintroduction%2Fhello_world%2Fsource%2F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the AMP page is validated and it has been already [cached by the AMP Cache](https://www-acuvuearabia-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.acuvuearabia.com/freetrial-amp). Read [here](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/#introduction) about the AMP Cache url format.

It can be that the AMP and the canonical are different in content so they are differently indexed. I don't think this is an AMP issue, but a SEO one. You have to create the correct search query for the AMP to appear in the search results and then you will find your AMP in the results. It is important that the content of your AMP and the canonical is the same!

Comment: Yes, you are right. We had a main image updated in canonical page but forget to update in AMP version. It fixed after the image updated. Thanks very much.